# Is there a better way to write this .htaccess directive?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want all css, javascript, and image file requests, that are named like this "filename.12345.css" to be re-routed to "filename.css".

The ".12345" part will always be numbers and the length can be anywhere from 11 - 15 characters.

This directive seems to work OK but I want to make sure there is no error in my logic.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(.+)\.(js|css|jpg|gif|png)$ $1.$3
```

Any help would be greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extra periods can interfere.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.([^.]+)\.(js|css|jpg|gif|png)$ $1.$3
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|jpg|gif|png)$ $1.$3
```

Comment: I knew there was something missing. Thanks!